# Second homology group of a presentation complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, finite-groups, cw-complexes

I am trying to learn results related to the presentation complex of a group and I am new to this subject. So I apologize if the questions are silly.

Given a finite group $G$, and a presentation $P$ of $G$, consider the presentation complex $X_P$. I have computed using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the group $S_3$ (the symmetric group of order $6$) and get $H_2(X_P,\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$ (in fact it is torsion-free). Also, by using a similar method I was able to show that for finite cyclic groups $H_2(X_P,\mathbb{Z})=0$. I have the following questions:

1. Is $H_2(X_P,\mathbb{Z})$ always torsion-free for a finite group $G$?
2. Can we put some restriction on $G$ (here $G$ is a finite group) so that $H_2(X_P,\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$?

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly, but isn't this just the Schur multiplier for $G$? In this case, the answer to 1 is no -- the Schur multiplier of $C_2 \times C_2$ is $C_2$ (as is the Schur multiplier for $S_n$ with $n>3$, I believe).

Comment: The presentation complex has dimension at most 2 and the 2-dimensional homology of a 2-dimensional complex with coefficients in the integers is always free.

Comment: To get the Schur multiplier you need at least the 3-skeleton of a classifying space

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Ah, thanks! That's what I was missing.

Comment: You can read a lot about presentation complexes from the book "Combinatorial group theory" by Lyndon&Schupp. (That text is a great starting point for anyone trying to learn low-dimensional topology from algebraic point of view!)